# unsigned tinyint in php?

Tags: php, types, integer

I'm working on a class to manipulate html hex color codes in php. Internally, the class treats RGB values as decimals. When I'm adding or subtracting, I never want the value to exceed 255 nor 'subceed' zero.

If course, I can do something piecemeal like

```
if ( $val >  255 ) {
    $val = 255;
} 
if ( $val < 0 ) {
    $val = 0;
}
```

But that's verbose :P

**Is there a clever, one-linish way I can get the value to stay between 0 and 255?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could possibly say something like:
$val = max(0, min(255, $val));

Answer (score 1):

Using the [bitwise OR operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) would work

```
if(($num | 255) === 255) { /* ... */ }
```

Example:

```
foreach (range(-1000, 1000) as $num) {
    if(($num | 255) === 255) {
        echo "$num, ";
    };
}
```

would print out all the numbers from 0 to 255.

Comment: Why bothering ORing? A simple `$var &= 0xFF` will mask the value to a 0-255 range

Comment: @MarcB what's *bothering* about using OR?

Comment: Marc B's answer makes sense - I don't get what Gordon's trying to achieve.

Comment: @symcbean using `$var &= 0xFF` to flip the value over makes as much sense as OR'ing `$num` to validate it's between 0 and 255 (which is what my code does). Both approaches are not the equivalent to the OPs `if` block to which @Narcissus already gave a one-liner, but alternate approaches to the problem.

Comment: @gordon. Sorry, typo. Meant "why bother with". But consider that this filtered number may need to be used elsewhere. Your version guaratees a maximum of 255, but also forces everything to be 255. Using the bit-wise AND leaves the number in a usable state.

Comment: @MarcB it's not forcing anything to be 255. It either is or is not. Mine is a mere validation, while yours is a transformation. I'd say both is fine, depending on the use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could be that guy who uses nested ternary operators.

eg.

```
( ($num > 255) ? 255 : ( ($num < 0) ? 0 : $num) )
```

Comment: nested ternary operators are only fun for personal arousement.

Comment: They were asking for a clever single line of code, and I think this satisfies that definition (except for the extra line of documentation that you would need to include)

Comment: @Jonathan I am with you to the end. Would that I had more than one point to give.