# How do I match number from 0 to 255 using regex in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

`/[0-9]+/` will also match those out of range,like `999`

How to write an regex that matches exactly numbers between `0~255` ?

Comment: With or without leading zeros?,  i.e. 001, etc.

Comment: *(related)* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738762/unsigned-tinyint-in-php

Answer (score 17):

I would do:

```
$n >= 0 && $n <= 255
```

Regex are good but they can be avoided in cases like these.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html):

```
000..255:       ^([01][0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$ 
0 or 000..255:  ^([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution would be grab the number, convert to an integer and then test that it's value is <= 255. But if you *really, **really*** want a regex to do it, then this would work:

```
^([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
```

**Edit** Fixed cause it didn't work in all situations. To be honest, this is why you should just parse the string into an integer and test that the integer value is <= 255.

Comment: That does **not** match 150 to 199 btw

Answer (score 2):

first group matches 0-99, second one 100-199, third 200-249, fourth 250-255

```
/[0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]/
```

Answer (score 1):

In reality, you should just match 0-999 and normalise the values afterwards, but...

```
/(25[0-5])|(2[0-4][0-9])|(1[0-9][0-9])|([0-9][0-9])|([0-9]))/
```

Comment: Or just catch any integer with /(\d+)/